# ModSecurity 3.0 doesn't block POST requests

Tags: apache, post, xss, mod-security, mod-security2

ModSecurity 3 doesn't seem to be blocking anything sent through post (like forms).
Logs say:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 200 (phase 2). detected XSS using
> libinjection. [file
> "/usr/local/coreruleset-3.3.0/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"]
> [line "37"] [id "941100"] [rev ""] [msg "XSS Attack Detected via
> libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: XSS data found within ARGS:text:
>
> alert('XSS')"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"]
>
> [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag
> "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag
> "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242"]
> [hostname "fullserver.ru"] [uri "/support/ticket.php"] [unique_id
> "1630221362"] [ref
> "v1106,29t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]

But the request is being sent straight into database and added there.

GET requests like that are momentarily blocked in browser with 403.

I tried setting

> SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,deny,status:403"
>
> SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,auditlog,deny,status:403"

But no luck there, nothing changed.

I don't know what to do, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching your configuration for other SecDefaultAction and be sure there's no one with 'status:200'. Also be sure you are not running ModSecurity in DetectionOnly mode (see modsecurity.conf).